# Get path of Paperclip file when it is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Is there any way to get path of Paperclip file before saving file?

For example,

### Person.rb

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo_file
end
```

### in some .rb

```
p = Person.new
p.photo_file.path
```

This returns nil.
But I want to get path.

Because I want to get url for direct uploading to S3.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def s3_put_url(path)
  s3 = AWS::S3.new(
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  )
  bucket_name = ENV['AWS_BUCKET']
  bucket = s3.buckets[bucket_name]

  path.slice!(0,1) if path[0] == '/'    
  object = bucket.objects[path]

  @s3url = object.url_for(:put, { :expires => 10*60 }).to_s
end
```

I have the method in Person model like this, 
but when photo_file is empty yet, I can't get path of path of Paperclip file.
Any advise will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: If there is no photo yet, then there will be no photo path to get. Am I misunderstanding what you're trying to ask?

Comment: Yes, thanks! But the path is fixed before uploading photo.  
For example, persons/photo_files/000/000/003/original.png.  
Of course, before uploading, if you access the pass, url is missing.
But I want to get this.